# How to select this element in selenium? Want to automate pulling metrics from Google Analytics

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation

I've tried everything, but can't seem to select this element within the Google Analytics page. I'm trying to automate pulling metrics every week. Any suggestions would help, thank you! Below is a copy of my code (username and pw retracted of course!) ^_^

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import request
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import lxml


# Get to the metrics page on Google Analytics
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/? 
authuser=1#/report-home/a127318841w186198941p183230211")
email_field = 
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='identifier']")
email_field.send_keys('asdf')
email_btn = browser.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
time.sleep(1)
password_field = 
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
password_field.send_keys('asdf')
password_btn = browser.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
time.sleep(15)
behavior_btn = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Behavior').click()
time.sleep(1)
behavior_btn = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Site Content').click()
time.sleep(1)
behavior_btn = browser.find_element_by_link_text('All Pages').click()
time.sleep(10)

unique_page_views = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ID- 
rowTable']/thead/tr[2]/td[4]/div[1]/div/p[3]")
print(unique_page_views)
time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
```

[The webpage with target element highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPNv.png)

Comment: use the analytics API, not selenium!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in here is you are trying to access the content from an iframe. You cannot traverse through `<iframe>`'s until switching to them.

You need to switch driver context via

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframeIdentifier)
```

Also, to discover that I had to log-in to analytics and find that particular object myself. Please be more considerate when asking questions and provide all the details you can.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry, I took a picture and linked it at the bottom where it reads "The webpage with target element highlighted." Like I said, I'm still a nub, so I wasn't sure what information you needed. I'll take a look into this and let you know what I find. Again, thank you so much :)

Comment: Update! This worked. You're going to have to sift through and find the iframeIdentifier, but once you do that, it works like a charm! Thanks again Overseer :)